# Can a global exception handler deal with exceptions in an awaited function?

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, exception

I've got a WPF desktop app that invokes tasks in background threads like this:

```
private async void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    await DoSomething();
  });      
}

public async Task DoSomething()
{
  //do something that throws an exception, mocked like this
  throw new Exception("Test");
}
```

I've got top level exception handlers in App startup like this:

```
this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
```

and those handlers all just log the exception to a file.

If I put the entire contents of `DoSomething` in a try/catch block, the catch works and the Task completes.

But if an exception is thrown that isn't in a try/catch, the `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` handler **is** being called, but the `IsTerminating` property is true and the app crashes.

How can I set up a global exception handler that will handle the exception without crashing my process, without having to put try/catch handling in every single method that might be invoked on a non-Dispatcher thread?

Comment: In your sample code, the `DoSomething()` method simply throws an exception on the dispatcher thread and then the `OnDispatcherUnhandledException` handler should be invoked first. Is this really what you are doing or is it just a bad example?

Comment: Yes, bad example. Updating the code to show the actual problem.

Comment: I changed the code to show a simple way of invoking `DoSomething` from a non-Dispatcher thread. This is the true issue; as you realized, the other one does indeed throw `Dispatcher.UnhandledException` and that is easily handled.

Comment: You should put a try/catch around each *await*, i.e. in SomeButton_Click in your sample code. await propagates that exception that the Task.Run catches.

Comment: Hmm, that does work. But this means that you can't really have a global handler; you need to handle each such code block manually, which is undesirable. It would be nicer to be able to set this globally so that they can all be handled with the same code and so if you miss one, it doesn't crash the app.

Comment: No it wouldn't. The only meaningful thing a global catch handler can do is to log the exception and then terminate the application. Ignoring an unexpected exception and carry on like nothing happened may potentially be much worse than have the application crashing. Don't do this.

Comment: I guess that's right, although the same is true of an error on the main thread, but you can handle that and continue on without necessarily fixing the underlying problem.

Comment: You can but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

In the `OnDispatcherUnhandledException` event handler you should set `Handled` property to `true`.

```
private void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   // log
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: My example code was bad. I updated to show that the `DoSomething` code is being invoked in a non-Dispatcher thread. This is what I'm actually doing and it crashes the app unless in a try/catch block.